# GitHub OAuth is not configured. Configure OAuth in the che.properties file

Tags: eclipse, oauth, eclipse-che

I am getting error to configure the OAuth in the che.property. but I am not able to find the location of the file and the syntax to add the configurations. I am using Ubuntu 18.04[image]

Answer (score 3):

For single-user Che, see https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/version-control/#configuring-github-oauth_version-control.

For multi-user Che:

1. Go to the keycloak page (http://keycloak-che.192.168.99.170.nip.io/)
2. login as admin
3. click Identity Providers.
4. In the Add provider drop-down list, click GitHub. The Add identity provider window is displayed.

In the Add identity provider window:

- The Redirect URI field, depending on your Eclipse Che installation,
  type the Authorization callback URL.
- Copy the client ID and the client secret from GitHub and paste them
  in the Client ID and the Client Secret fields, respectively.
- In the Homepage URL and the Authorization callback URL field,
  depending on your Eclipse Che installation, type the two URLS.
- In the Default Scopes field, type repo, user, write:publick_key.
- Set Store Tokens and Stored Tokens Readable to ON.
- Click Save.

The Success! The github provider has been created. message indicates success. And, the GitHub provider is added to the Identity Providers window.

Perform the following steps to set role mapping for non-administrative users.

1. Expand the Manage tab and then click Users.
2. Click the Role Mappings tab.
3. Click the Client Roles drop-down menu and click broker.
4. In the Available Roles list, click read-token.
5. Click Add selected.
6. In the Effective Roles list, click read-token.
7. The GitHub OAuth is now set for the user.